# How can I combine rank=same with dir=back, while specifying ports?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a graph that uses [HTML-like labels](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) to create tables where some cells are connected by an edge.

This works well, but when I specify `rank=same` for two nodes, `dir=back` for the connecting edge and at least one [port position](https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/portPos/) the edge direction is not respected.

This shows an [example](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20so%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20This%20all%20works%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%20-%3E%20b%20%5Blabel%3D%22Regular%20direction%22%20dir%3D%22forward%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%20-%3E%20d%20%5Blabel%3D%22Reverse%20direction%22%2C%20dir%3D%22back%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20e%3Aw%20-%3E%20f%3Aw%20%5Blabel%3D%22Reverse%20direction%5Cn%20%2B%20port%20choice%22%2C%20dir%3D%22back%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20g%20-%3E%20h%20%5Blabel%3D%22Reverse%20direction%5Cn%20%2B%20rank%3Dsame%22%2C%20dir%3D%22back%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7Brank%3Dsame%3B%20g%3B%20h%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20This%20fails%0D%0A%20%20%20%20i%3As%20-%3E%20j%20%5Blabel%3D%22Reverse%20direction%5Cn%20%2B%20port%20choice%5Cn%20%2B%20rank%3Dsame%22%2C%20dir%3D%22back%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7Brank%3Dsame%20i%3B%20j%7D%0D%0A%7D):

```
digraph so {
    // This all works
    a -> b [label="Regular direction" dir="forward"]
    c -> d [label="Reverse direction", dir="back"]
    e:w -> f:w [label="Reverse direction\n + port choice", dir="back"]
    g -> h [label="Reverse direction\n + rank=same", dir="back"]
    {rank=same; g; h}
    
    // This fails
    i:s -> j [label="Reverse direction\n + port choice\n + rank=same", dir="back"]
    {rank=same i; j}
}
```

I've highlighted the failing part below:
[image]

**Is there a combination of graph/node/edge options that would allow me to draw a reverse edge from one node port to another, while the two nodes are at the same rank?**

#### What I've tried

Instead of using `dir=back` on the edge, I tried setting the [`arrowhead=none` and `arrowtail=normal`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/arrowType/) in combination with `dir=both`. That [didn't work either](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20so%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20This%20fails%0D%0A%20%20%20%20i%3As%20-%3E%20j%20%5Blabel%3D%22Reverse%20direction%5Cn%20%2B%20port%20choice%5Cn%20%2B%20rank%3Dsame%22%2C%20dir%3D%22back%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7Brank%3Dsame%20i%3B%20j%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20This%20fails%0D%0A%20%20%20%20k%3As%20-%3E%20l%20%5Blabel%3D%22Reverse%20direction%5Cn%20%2B%20port%20choice%5Cn%20%2B%20rank%3Dsame%5Cn%20%2B%20arrowhead%2Ftail%22%2C%20arrowhead%3Dnone%2C%20arrowtail%3Dnormal%2C%20dir%3D%22both%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7Brank%3Dsame%20k%3B%20l%7D%0D%0A%7D) and somehow even affects the  `i -> j` edge as well.

```
digraph so {
    // This fails
    i:s -> j [label="Reverse direction\n + port choice\n + rank=same", dir="back"]
    {rank=same i; j}
    
    // This fails
    k:s -> l [label="Reverse direction\n + port choice\n + rank=same\n + arrowhead/tail", arrowhead=none, arrowtail=normal, dir="both"]
    {rank=same k; l}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that mentioning the `dir` attribute before the `label` attribute gets you what you want:

```
digraph so {
    i:s -> j [dir="back", label="Reverse direction\n + port choice\n + rank=same"]
    {rank=same; i;j}
}
```